# How to make the cards turn over?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to turn the cards around in this game, but I can't. I tried to do some things by manipulating the state, but to no avail. What I want to do is: When I click on the button that is in the Header component, all the cards must turn over. How can I do this?

**Code:**

```
import { imagesUrl } from "../../constants/urls"
import useRequestData from "../../hooks/useRequestData"
import { Card, Container, Footer } from "./styledTarotCard"

    const TarotCard = () => {
        const getTarot = useRequestData([], "tarot.json")
    
        const renderCard = getTarot?.cards?.map((card) => {
            return (
                <Card key={card.name}>
                    <img src={`${imagesUrl}${card.image}`} alt={"Imagem da Carta"} />
                    <Footer>
                        <p>{card.name}</p>
                    </Footer>
                </Card>
            )
        })
    
        return (
            <Container>
                {renderCard}
            </Container>
        )
    }
    
    export default TarotCard
```

**Demo:** http://muddled-shirt.surge.sh/

Comment: You can use `visibility: hidden;` to hide it. It will be similar to turn over.

Comment: You have to create a "card" component. Create a state "isTurnedOver" initialized to `true`.

You add a `click` event on the card that changes the "isTurnedOver" state to `false`.

Finally, in the div of your card you display or not the image according to "isTurnedOver" state.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/card-flip

Basically, you would create two faces and apply some CSS magic (`transform`, `backface-visibility`, ...) and switch classes when you click or hover over a card.

Comment: It might work, but that's not exactly how I want to do it in this case. I edited the question to make it clearer.